# libtool: link: cannot find the library /usr/src/freeswitch/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib/libexpat.la

Tags: ubuntu, freeswitch

I am getting following error while installing freeswitch on Ubuntu.

libtool: link: cannot find the library /usr/src/freeswitch/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib/libexpat.la' or unhandled argument/usr/src/freeswitch/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib/libexpat.la'

Any idea to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expat is an XML parser library written in C. project website

You need to download the package from project page

Read installation instructions from the README file. Basically you need to

```
./configure
make
make install
```